# Maven fluido skin always renders left navigation empty on site

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-site-plugin

I couldn't get the `maven-fluido-skin` work completely - the left navigation section (the section that contains links to various project details) is always rendered empty. Not sure if I'm missing some skin configuration, but I'd have thought of this functionality to be available to its users out-of-the-box.

[image]

Any additional gadgets that I add, like the `google search`, do appear on the left navigation section though.

Here's how my `site descriptor` looks:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.4.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/decoration-1.4.0.xsd"
  name="Project name">
  <skin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
  </skin>

  <custom>
    <fluidoSkin>
      <profile>pre-release</profile>
      <sourceLineNumbersEnabled>true</sourceLineNumbersEnabled>
      <breadcrumbDivider>»</breadcrumbDivider>
    </fluidoSkin>
  </custom>
</project>
```

I use `3.4` version of `maven-site-plugin` and `1.3.1` version of `maven-fluido-skin` and `2.2.1` version of maven distribution.

FWIW, the default skin works just fine - it's got the left navigation correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I see why now. Unlike the other skins, fluido expects us to specify all the `menu`s and `item`s explicitly in the `site.xml` which I didn't do. That's the reason the left nav bar was rendered empty every time.

Answer (score 5):

You can save some time by using menu references and avoid to specify the item nodes explicitely by using the following menu references which are supported and generated by maven-site-plugin :

```
<menu ref="parent" />
<menu ref="modules" />
<menu ref="reports"/>
```